# How to open R Code in R studio that is buried in folders

Tags: r, rstudio

I am attempting to open an R code file. I navigate to the file in the folder. Open it and get the following error in R Studio: "Error while opening file: The system cannot find the file specified"

My hunch is that is has something to do with the number of folders the file is buried in.

So, weirdly when I move the R code file I want to open into the folder before the folder it is currently in, it is able to find it. I don't understand why this is happening.

For example, say I want to open the file called "R Code.R".

In my system, if the file exists in this directory. It won't open.

```
C:\Users\Shari\OneDrive\University of California, Davis\Fourth Year\Dissertation Prospectus\Out of State Donors\R Code\Analysis - Master\Redistricting and Amount Analysis\Amount\Continuity Score - New\Main Effects
```

But if I put it one directory up:

```
C:\Users\Shari\OneDrive\University of California, Davis\Fourth Year\Dissertation Prospectus\Out of State Donors\R Code\Analysis - Master\Redistricting and Amount Analysis\Amount\Continuity Score - New
```

It will open.

Any ideas as to why this is happening or how to resolve it?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens, but are you using Projects? Because you should always use RStudio Projects. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-RStudio-Projects

Comment: Have a look here <https://here.r-lib.org/>. I think this will help.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: It's a guess on my part (I did a brief search without success) that instead of folder change being the difference, maybe it's the length of the path that is causing the problem?  I think it's low probability, but keep in the back of mind as you search.

Comment: Try using getAnywhere()

Comment: I suspect it could be a path too long, perhaps like here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd

Comment: The max length of a file name is, I think 260 characters (according to the link Jon Spring posted). Depending on your exact file name, that might exceed the limit if it is particularly long. Putting it in the parent folder might just have it under the limit. Try and see if you can open a file with a very very short name in the same location.

Comment: Hi All, thank you all for your wonderful set of helpful comments. I greatly appreciate it.  
wackojacko1997, JonSpring, and thehand0 I think you are right. It appears to be a result of a long file name / path name.  I tried shortening the name and it was successfully able to open the R Code. Assuming this is the issue, how might I be able to get around it? Does this mean I'll just need to be more conscious of folder systems I use, use R Studio Projects (thanks Simon Woodward), or some other resolution?

Comment: @wackojacko1997 I'm using Windows 10